# How do I grep all 32 character long strings given only the first five Characters?

Tags: regex, string, grep

I want to find all strings that start with abcd and are 32 characters long,
What I've been trying to do is:

```
 find / -type f | grep -cr '^4bceb[a-z0-9]\{27\}*'
```

The output is:

```
    flag22:0
find: ‘/snap/core/5742/etc/chatscripts’: Permission denied
flag32.mp3:0
.bash_logout:0
flag23:0
find: ‘/snap/core/5742/etc/ppp/peers’: Permission denied
grep: .ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
grep: .ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied
grep: .ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
grep: .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
.lesshst:0
find: output.txt:0
.bash_history:0
‘/snap/core/5742/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
flag20:0
flag19:0
.cache/motd.legal-displayed:0
.viminfo:0
.flag18:0
.bashrc:0
.profile:0
flag17:0
```

When I replace the initial 5 characters with a range like so I get a ton of matches, but do not grep the actual strings:

```
find / -type f | grep -cr '[a-z0-9]\{32\}*'
```

Output:

```
flag22:1
flag32.mp3:235
.bash_logout:7
flag23:1
grep: .ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
grep: .ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied
grep: .ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
grep: .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
.lesshst:3
find: ‘/snap/core/5742/etc/chatscripts’: Permission denied
find: ‘/snap/core/5742/etc/ppp/peers’: Permission denied
find: ‘/snap/core/5742/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
output.txt:62730
.bash_history:40
flag20:1
flag19:3001
.cache/motd.legal-displayed:0
.viminfo:166
.flag18:1
.bashrc:117
.profile:20
flag17:1
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to find files whose names are 32 characters long and start with `abcd` or are you saying you want to get the names of files that contain a string that's 32 characters long and start with `abcd` or are you saying you want to get all strings that are 32 characters long and start with `abcd` or something else? Please [edit] your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I want to get all strings that are 32 characters long and start with abcd

Comment: Again - please [edit] your question to include some concise, testable sample input and expected output. You might want to use strings that are, say, 8 characters long rather than 32 to make it easier for you to come up with the example and us to read it - you can always extrapolate an answer you get for 8 chars to work for 32.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ed! I clarified the question for future people who might come across it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find all strings that start with `abcd` and are `32`
> characters long, e.g. `abcd05d85801f62c4c0d05d3a76432e0`

Use the regex, `^abcd\w{28}$` for your requirement. Note that `\w` also matches `_` (an underscore). If you do not want to match an underscore character, use the regex, `^abcd[A-Za-z0-9]{28}$`.

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/bDWa8m/7) for a demo and the description of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -wE 'abcd.{28}'
```

will `get all strings that are 32 characters long and start with abcd` but without any sample input/output it's a guess if that's really what you want or not.